# XSLT: find position of node in a given nodeset

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Imagine an XML tree with nodes in several depths

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <ELEM2>
    <ELEM3/>
  </ELEM2>
  <ELEM2>
    <ELEM3/>
  </ELEM2>
  <ELEM2>
    <ELEM3/>
  </ELEM2>
</root>
```

I would like to know the unique position of each element in the entire tree.

**Desired output:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <root position="1"/>
    <ELEM2 position="2"/>
      <ELEM3 position="3"/>
    <ELEM2 position="4"/>
      <ELEM3 position="5"/>
    <ELEM2 position="6"/>
      <ELEM3 position="7"/>
```

So, basically, I'd like to see the position in the list of all elements, and use that index to find it.

**Attempt 1: `position()`:** I tried using `position()` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="position">
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gave me duplicated position attributes:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <root position="1"/>
    <ELEM2 position="2"/>
      <ELEM3 position="2"/>
    <ELEM2 position="4"/>
      <ELEM3 position="2"/>
    <ELEM2 position="6"/>
      <ELEM3 position="2"/>
```

So, I cannot use `position()` in the current nodeset, since that position is limited to the current branch in the tree.

**Attempt 2: `preceding::`:**

Then I looked at using `preceding::` like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="position">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::*)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But unfortunately I got this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root position="0"/>
  <ELEM2 position="0"/>
    <ELEM3 position="0"/>
  <ELEM2 position="2"/>
    <ELEM3 position="2"/>
  <ELEM2 position="4"/>
    <ELEM3 position="4"/>
```

So, `preceding::`: counts siblings on the axis of the parents sibling and up to the root.

**Attempt 3: `preceding-sibling::`:**

Not even worth it. This will only look through position of other sibling elements, which mean I will get same positions for each of the ELEM3 elements.

**Attempt 4: `generate-id()`:**

This was a slightly different approach if we relax the limitation that the @position attribute reflects a node number. This doesn't matter in my setup as long as the generated value is unique.

This one will generate unique @position attributes. Unfortunately the ids are only guaranteed to be same within the same run. This means I cannot use this for tests and our CI/test setup.

**Attempt 5: Find current node in given list?**

I am thinking if I can in some way provide the list of elements via an XPATH like so: `*` or `ELEM2|ELEM3`. Now if I could  then take the `current()` node and find it's position in the list.

Is this possible?

Limitations:

- I am using XSLT 1/xsltproc
- generated @position attributes must be unique
- generated @position attributes must be relatively stable and not change between runs or platforms

Comment: A simple XPath expression calculates the wanted number... No need to use `<xsl:number>`, which sometimes can be pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<xsl:number count="*" level="any"/>`:

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhEaiH

Answer (score 1):

**Or simply**:

```
count(ancestor::*) + count(preceding::*) +1
```

**Here is a complete transformation** (just 10 lines):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="position" select="count(ancestor::*) + count(preceding::*) +1"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <ELEM2>
        <ELEM3/>
    </ELEM2>
    <ELEM2>
        <ELEM3/>
    </ELEM2>
    <ELEM2>
        <ELEM3/>
    </ELEM2>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<root position="1">
      <ELEM2 position="2">
            <ELEM3 position="3"/>
      </ELEM2>
      <ELEM2 position="4">
            <ELEM3 position="5"/>
      </ELEM2>
      <ELEM2 position="6">
            <ELEM3 position="7"/>
      </ELEM2>
</root>
```